# Kendo Grid custom group header template show aggregates in multiple columns

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have been searching everywhere, and am desperate to find a solution.

I have exactly the same problem as posted in this following link:

[kendoui grid custom group header with columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36408882/kendoui-grid-custom-group-header-with-columns)

I am hoping that at this time this issue is fixed.

If not, can someone provide any better work around? The answer from the above mentioned post does not give me the ability to line up the group header with columns when column size changes.

Answer (score 1):

All currently defined aggregates are available in the [columns.groupHeaderTemplate](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.groupHeaderTemplate) under "aggregates":

[Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/uxEpo)

You can manipulate the layout via DOM manipulations as necessary in the [dataBound](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-dataBound) and [columnResize event](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-columnResize) handler.